# OpenGL (with OpenTK) isn't displaying square

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk, .net-core-3.1

I'm using the following code to display multiple textured Squares in a 3D-Environment, but there is not a single Square showing up (OpenGL doesn't output any errors), but I'm able to see my Background-Color:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;
layout (location = 3) in mat4 aInstanceMatrix;

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;
    gl_Position = projection * view * aInstanceMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0f); 
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture, TexCoords);
}
```

Code of Drawer:

```
class Drawer
    {
        private static float[] SquareVertices = new float[]
        {
            //aPos               //aTexCoords
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
             0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f
        };

        public static unsafe void DrawSquares(Shader shader, Camera camera, Texture texture, List<Matrix4> instanceMatrices)
        {
            //Configure instanced array
            Matrix4[] instanceMatricesArray = instanceMatrices.ToArray();
            int instancedVBO = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, instancedVBO);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, instanceMatricesArray.Length, instanceMatricesArray, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            int squareVAO = GL.GenVertexArray();
            

            // set transformation matrices as an instance vertex attribute
            GL.BindVertexArray(squareVAO);
            // set attribute pointers for matrix (4 times vec4)
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(3);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(3, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(Matrix4), 0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(4);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(4, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(Matrix4), sizeof(Vector4));
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(5);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(5, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(Matrix4), 2 * sizeof(Vector4));
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(6);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(6, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(Matrix4), 3 * sizeof(Vector4));

            GL.VertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
            GL.VertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
            GL.VertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
            GL.VertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);

            GL.BindVertexArray(0);

            //Set uniforms
            shader.Use();
            shader.SetMatrix4("projection", camera.GetProjectionMatrix());
            shader.SetMatrix4("view", camera.GetViewMatrix());
            shader.SetInt("texture", 0);
            texture.Use();

            GL.BindVertexArray(squareVAO);
            GL.DrawElementsInstanced(PrimitiveType.Triangles, SquareVertices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, SquareVertices, instanceMatricesArray.Length);
        }
    }
```

I already tested that the texture is succesfully loaded and that the shader-program (here Shader class) compiled without errors. I also ensured that the texture is created correctly and can be used via Texture.Use() in TextureUnit0. In my example instanceMatrices only contains one **Identity** Matrix.
If anyone needs it here is the code of my camera, which starts at 0 0 0:

```
public class Camera
{
    private Vector3 _front = -Vector3.UnitZ;
    private Vector3 _up = Vector3.UnitY;
    private Vector3 _right = Vector3.UnitX;

    private float _pitch;
    private float _yaw = -MathHelper.PiOver2;
    private float _fov = MathHelper.PiOver2;

    public Camera(Vector3 position, float aspectRatio)
    {
        Position = position;
        AspectRatio = aspectRatio;
    }

    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public float AspectRatio { private get; set; }

    public Vector3 Front => _front;
    public Vector3 Up => _up;
    public Vector3 Right => _right;

    public float Pitch
    {
        get => MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(_pitch);
        set
        {
            var angle = MathHelper.Clamp(value, -89f, 89f);
            _pitch = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(angle);
            UpdateVectors();
        }
    }

    public float Yaw
    {
        get => MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(_yaw);
        set
        {
            _yaw = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(value);
            UpdateVectors();
        }
    }

    public float Fov
    {
        get => MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(_fov);
        set
        {
            var angle = MathHelper.Clamp(value, 1f, 45f);
            _fov = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(angle);
        }
    }

    public Matrix4 GetViewMatrix()
    {
        return Matrix4.LookAt(Position, Position + _front, _up);
    }

    public Matrix4 GetProjectionMatrix()
    {
        return Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(_fov, AspectRatio, 0.01f, 100f);
    }

    private void UpdateVectors()
    {
        _front.X = (float)Math.Cos(_pitch) * (float)Math.Cos(_yaw);
        _front.Y = (float)Math.Sin(_pitch);
        _front.Z = (float)Math.Cos(_pitch) * (float)Math.Sin(_yaw);
        _front = Vector3.Normalize(_front);

        _right = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(_front, Vector3.UnitY));
        _up = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(_right, _front));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The information you have provided is insufficient for me to know why you are not seeing anything on your screen, however, I recommend the following

1. Render a triangle with colour attributes, this will require you to create a shader class in a Class Library in the properties giving it an assembly name and default namespace eg LearnOpenTK.Common, if you succeed with this
2. create an instance of the shader and camera class but this will require access to the namespace that was created hence you will need to using LearnOpenTK.Common; as one of the namespaces so that the instance can access the shader and camera class.
3. If you are still unable to see anything go to the shader files and then properties go to copy output directory and set it to copy always.

If this does not work, can you provide sufficient information about what you can see from a basic triangle and then try to transform your textured object.

For more information refer to https://opentk.net/